# Redirect customers if the cart is empty

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

i want to redirect all my customers after login or registration to Dashboard if their cart is empty and to Checkout if they have products in cart. I use extension to do this redirection after login but is work only if is a product in cart. How I can sort this? This is my code:

```
   if (Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isEnabled() && !Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getRedirectregister()){    
       $lasturl = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl();
     if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(), 'checkout') === false){
         if (! preg_match("#customer/account/create#", $lasturl) && Mage::helper('customerredirect')->isoptionEnabled('login_customerredirect')) {
                  if($this->_CustomerGroup()) {
                   $_session = $this->_getSession();
                   $_session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customerredirect')->setRedirectOnLogin());
                 }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work like a charm...

```
app/etc/modules/Namespace_RedirectLogin.xml
```

Contains

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_RedirectLogin>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Namespace_RedirectLogin>
    </modules>
</config>
```

next

```
local/Namespace/RedirectLogin/etc/config.xml
```

Contains

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_RedirectLogin>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Namespace_RedirectLogin>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <namespace_redirectlogin>
                <class>Namespace_RedirectLogin_Model</class>
            </namespace_redirectlogin>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <customer_login>
                <observers>
                    <namespace_redirectlogin_customer_login>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>namespace_redirectlogin/observer</class>
                        <method>customerLogin</method>
                    </namespace_redirectlogin_customer_login>
                </observers>
            </customer_login>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and

```
local/Namespace/RedirectLogin/Model/Observer.php
```

Contains

```
<?php
class Namespace_RedirectLogin_Model_Observer
{

     public function customerLogin($observer)
     {
        $numberOfItems = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
        if($numberOfItems > 0){
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }else{ 
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('cust‌​omer/account'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }



     }

}
```

To detect 'customer login action', i have used `customer_login` event. In this point, all I have to do was to check if cart contains products and redirect the user to the corresponding page.

Comment: thank you alex, but i see there is only when the $numberOfItems > 0 but how we can redirect to dashboard when $numberOfItems < 0 ?

Comment: see my updated answer from above

Comment: i think we are almost there but I don't see there the registration is only the lfor ogin  process

Comment: This is working for registration as well as login. I have tested that.

Comment: ok I will try it right now

Comment: my answer helped you ? if so, please mark it as "answered". thanks

Comment: you're welcome !

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using observer.
Step 1.Create config file for your module.

> app/code/local/Arun/Rai/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Arun_Rai>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Arun_Rai>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <arun_rai>
                <class>Arun_Rai_Model</class>
            </arun_rai>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <customer_login>
                <observers>
                    <arun_rai_customer_login>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>arun_rai/observer</class>
                        <method>customerLogin</method>
                    </arun_rai_customer_login>
                </observers>
            </customer_login>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Step 2.Create observer file to setup your logic.

> app/code/local/Arun/Rai/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Arun_Rai_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerLogin($observer)
    {
        // you can put your business logic here
        $item = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
        if($item >0)
        {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }else{
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

Step 3.Register your Module

> app/etc/modules/Arun_Rai.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Arun_Rai>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Arun_Rai>
        </modules>
    </config>
```